# Recuperar string de inputStream

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

gracias de antemano por revisar esto que creo que es una tontería pero no consigo de ninguna manera obtener.

```
Thread(Runnable {
try {
val url = URL(" https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html")
val con = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
var contador: Int = 0
val datas = con.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
val arrayHtml = con.inputStream.bufferedReader().use{ it.readText()}
println(datas)
```

Intento almacenar todo lo que devuelve "con.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()" en un String, pero no hay manera, dentro de datas puedo imprimir por el Logcat el resultado HTML pero línea a línea, tiene que ser una tontería pero necesito recuperar/guardar toda la salida HTML en un String, o incluso en un array de Strings

Gracias de antemano,

Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método que estás buscando es [reduce](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html). Este método reduce una colección a un único elemento que es el resultado de acumular todos los elementos de la colección. En este ejemplo los acumulo agregando un salto de línea (`\n`) entre cada una:

```
val url = URL("https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html")
val datas = url.openStream().bufferedReader().useLines { lines ->
    lines.reduce { accumulator, currentLine ->
        "$accumulator\n$currentLine"
    }
}
println(datas)
```

Alternativamente puedes usar `fold()` que hace lo mismo pero toma un valor inicial. Esto evita que ocurra una exception cuando la colección esté vacia:

```
lines.fold("") { accumulator, currentLine ->
    "$accumulator\n$currentLine"
}
```

Comment: Cuando intento mostrar el contenido del valor datas así:
 `textBox.text = datas.toString()` 
Me devuelve lo siguiente: 
`[Ljava.lang.String;@bb75335e`

Entiendo que pueda ser porque estoy recuperando el contenido de datas fuera del Thread(Runnable

Comment: Ya te respondí en el otro post. Puedes aceptar esta respuesta? La otra es una pregunta diferente

Comment: Si, gracias a tu código se recupera todo en un único string, voy a probar lo que comentas en el otro post. Muchísimas gracias @Sinner of the System